# Django forms without widgets

Tags: django, django-forms

I understand that Django want to generate forms automatically so you don't have to do so in your template, and I do understand that many people find it cool.

But I have specific requirements and I have to write my forms on my own. I just need something to parse the data, be it a form submitted using a user interface, or an API request, or whatever.

I tried to use ModelForm, but it doesn't seem to work as I want it to work.

I'd like to have something with the following behavior:

- possibility to specify the model of the object I am going to create/update
- possibility to specify an object in case of an update
- possibility to provide new data in a dictionary

  - if I am creating a new object, missing fields in my data should be replaced by their default values as specified in my model definition
  - if I am updating an existing object, missing fields in my data should be replaced by the current values of the object I am updating. Another way of saying is, do not update values that are missing in my data dictionary.
- data validation should be performed before calling `save()`, and it should throw  a `ValidationError` with the list of erroneous fields and errors.

Currently, I prefer to do everything manually :

```
o = myapp.models.MyModel() # or o = myapp.Models.MyModel.objects.get(pk = data['pk'])
o.field1 = data['field1']
o.field2 = data['field2']
…
o.full_clean()
o.save()
```

It would be nice to have a shortcut :

```
o = SuperCoolForm(myapp.models.MyModel, data)
o.save()
```

Do you know if Django does provide a solution for this or am I asking too much?

Thank you!

Comment: Django does it all. But you have to read and learn from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) .

Comment: No it doesn't, as you can learn from the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).